# ggplot2 - highlight min/max bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

Without adding an extra column to the data.frame, is there a built-in way to highlight the min/max bar?  In the following example, I'd like the Joe bar to be green (max) and the John bar to be red (min).

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I couldn't find when searching:

```
data= data.frame( Name = c("Joe","Jane", "John") , Value = c(3,2,1) )
ggplot(data=data)+geom_bar(aes_string(x="Name",y="Value"), stat="identity" )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use subsetting:

```
p <- ggplot(data=data)+
     geom_bar(aes(x=Name, y=Value), stat="identity") +
     geom_bar(data=subset(data, Value==min(Value)), aes(Name, Value),
              fill="red", stat="identity") +
     geom_bar(data=subset(data, Value==max(Value)), aes(Name, Value),
              fill="green", stat="identity")
print(p)
```

[image: ggplot2 output]

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
ggplot(data, aes(Name, Value)) + 
 geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + 
 geom_bar(stat = 'identity', aes(fill = factor(Value)), 
   subset = .(Value %in% range(Value))) +    
 scale_fill_manual(values = c('red', 'green'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I would do it all in one go with an `ifelse` approach:

```
ggplot(data=data) + 
  geom_bar(aes_string(x="Name",y="Value", fill='factor(ifelse(Value==max(Value), 3, ifelse(Value==min(Value), 2, 1)))'), stat="identity" ) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c('gray20', 'red', 'green'), legend=F)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option using logical indexing via `which.min()` and `which.max()`:

```
ggplot(data, aes(Name, Value, stat = "identity")) + 
  geom_bar() +
  geom_bar(data = data[which.min(data$Value),], fill = "red") +
  geom_bar(data = data[which.max(data$Value),], fill = "green")
```

Comment: I think this will only work if you add aes(...) and stat = "Identity" like in @rcs example

Comment: @SFun28 - I can't find the reference, but any value that is set in `aes()` will be passed on to each subsequent layer, so `stat = "identity"` is implicitly supplied to each geom_layer.

Comment: @SFun28 - which is also why we didn't have to pass `Name` and `Value` explicitly.

Comment: Aesthetics get inherited but the stat is not an aesthetic.